# Application.GetResourceStream returns StreamResourceInfo where ContentType is empty

Tags: wpf, resources

I have 1 client where a call to Application.GetResourceStream returns a StreamResourceInfo object where the ContentType property is empty.

All other clients return a StreamResourceInfo object with ContentType = "image/png".

Does anyone have any idea, why this 1 client does not populate the ContentType property?
The Stream property is the same on all clients.

Best Regards,
Krimson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because the 1 client did not have the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png` in the Windows registry.